# Adonis using getters in a query with paginate fails

Tags: adonis.js

I am trying to use getters and return a status in my array data

So in my controller i have

```
  async index ({ request, response, view }) {
    const users = await User.query()
    .paginate(request.input("page"),request.input("perPage"))

   return response.send(users);
}
```

In my User model i have added

```
class User extends Model{
    getStatus (status_id) {
      return status_id?"active":"Inactive";
     }
 }
```

But when i check my data returned in the index function above it doesnt contain the status of either active or Inactive.What am i missing out?

Comment: show your migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters always write get and then camel case like `getStatusId`
you write this

```
class User extends Model{
    getStatusId(status_id) {
      return status_id?"active":"Inactive";
     }
 }
```

More About Getter visit [adonis official doc](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/database-getters-setters#_getters)